# Show that $a_{n}=2^{n} + 3^{n}$ if $a_{o}=2,a_{1}=5, a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_{n}, \ n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given the following sequence;
$a_{o}=2,a_{1}=5, a_{n+2}=5{a_{n+1}}-6a_{n},  n\in \mathbb{N}$
show that: $a_{n}=2^{n} + 3^{n}$...can somebody  solve it and explain too?

Comment: What does $5_{a_n+1}$ mean?

Comment: after a_{n} comes a_{n}+1 its the next number of the sequence

Comment: Do you mean to write $a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_n$?

Comment: yes thats what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be shown by mathematical induction.

The initial cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are easily shown. Now assume that the formula $a_n = 2^n+3^n$ is true for $n=k$ and $n=k+1$. Then by the recurrence formula and algebra,

\begin{align}
a_{k+2} &= 5a_{k+1} - 6a_k  \\[2ex]
 &= 5(2^{k+1}+3^{k+1}) - 6(2^k+3^k) \\[2ex]
 &= 5(2\cdot 2^k+3\cdot 3^k) - 6(2^k+3^k) \\[2ex]
 &= 4\cdot 2^k + 9\cdot 3^k \\[2ex]
 &= 2^{k+2} + 3^{k+2}
\end{align}

and the induction step is proved for $n=k+2$. Thus the statement is true for all $n$. I'll leave the steps to fit this in with your version of induction up to you--if you have trouble with that, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{n+2}+3^{n+2} = 5\left(2^{n+1} + 3^{n+1} \right) - 6\left( 2^n + 3^n\right)$$
$$4\cdot2^{n}+9 \cdot 3^{n} = 10\cdot 2^{n} + 15\cdot 3^{n}  - 6\cdot2^n-6 \cdot 3^n$$
$$10\cdot2^{n}+15 \cdot 3^{n} = 10\cdot 2^{n} + 15\cdot 3^{n}$$

Now to find the equation for $a_n$

We can use generating series: $G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$

We have $a_n = 5a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}$
$$G(x) = 5x + 2 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
$$G(x) = 5x + 2 + 5x\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-6x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^{n-2}$$
$$G(x) = 5x+2 + 5x(G(x)-2)-6x^2G(x)$$
$$G(x) = \frac{-5x+2}{1-5x+6x^2}$$
$$G(x) = \frac{-5x+2}{(1-2x)(1-3x)}$$
$$G(x) = \frac{1}{1-2x}+\frac{1}{1-3x}$$
$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x)^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(3x)^n$$
Clearly the coefficient of a given value of $x$ is $2^n + 3^n$

Comment: This just verifies that the given solution works, but does not show how to arrive at the solution.

Comment: I agree, but I wasn't sure if that's all the OP wants, since they give the solution already.

Comment: I assume that by "solve it" OP would want a derivation of the solution.

Comment: yes  john Lous solution doesnt show how he arrived at the conclusion of what i asked

Comment: Sure, I'll add that then

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n x^n}$. Multiply both sides of the recurrence relation by $x^{n+2}$ and sum over all $n\ge 0$ to get
$$
F(x)-5x-2=5x(F(x)-2)-6x^2F(x),
$$
which yields
$$
\begin{split}
F(x)&=\frac{2-5x}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{1}{1-2x}+\frac{1}{1-3x}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n x^n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{3^n x^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(2^n+3^n) x^n},
\end{split}
$$
so $a_n=2^n+3^n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the recurrence equation$$a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_{n}$$ the corresponding characteristic equation is $$r^2=5r-6$$ the roots of which being $r=2$ and $r=3$.

So, the general solution is $$a_n=c_12^n+c_2 3^n$$ Now, apply the given conditions
$$a_0=2 \implies c_1+c_2=2$$ $$a_1=5 \implies 2c_1+3c_2=5$$ Just solve these last equations for $c_1,c_2$.